# How to get to grub menu

Tags: grub2, recovery-mode

I want to get to ubuntu recovery mode and I don't know how to get to grub menu. I am using ubuntu 22. I tried to hold or press many keys such as esc or shift left/right. I switched on the computer and pressed one of the keys and nothing happed.

Comment: Did you try to change the value of `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` `0` to `5` in `/etc/default/grub` and then `update-grub`?

Comment: Can I update it without root privileges?

Comment: Can I restart it like I restart the computer instead of update-grub?

Comment: I restart it and it is still same